# how to restore a locally deleted folder?

Tags: svn

Locally deleting a file followed by svn update restores the local copy of that file. However this does not seem to apply to folders. Is there any way to make it work for folders as well?

EDIT:
This is what the console output looks like:

```
C:\svn\Google Project Hosting\xulwin\xulrunnersamples>rmdir /S /Q treeview

C:\svn\Google Project Hosting\xulwin\xulrunnersamples>svn up
D    treeview
Updated to revision 50.
```

EDIT2:
I have used svn for over two years now and I never had this error before. But I didn't change any settings. The only thing I can think of was that I created a Local Repository with Tortoise SVN today on my external hard drive to back up some unrelated old stuff. But that should not be the cause of the problem because the behavior occurs both on the local copy from this local repository and my code from Google Project Hosting.

EDIT3:
WTF I suddenly can't reproduce the bug anymore. It all works as it should now. But I didn't change anything.

EDIT4:
In EDIT1 the file seems to be marked as deleted, but it isn't since the svn commit command did nothing. Neither did Tortoise Check for modifications list anything.

Note: When the problem still occurred, a fully recursive update did restore the folder.

Comment: Have you tried using git?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I ran into this problem today with svn 1.5.6.
`svn up --force the_dir_path` fixed it for me.

To recreate:

```
$ svn up
Updated to revision X.
$ rm -rf the_dir_path
$ svn up
D the_dir_path
Updated to revision X.
$ svn up
Updated to revision X.
$ svn up --force the_dir_path
A ....
A ....
Updated to revision X.
```

Comment: For everyone trying to type 'dir' literally (like me), it should be replace with the actual directory you want to get back

Comment: This is the only answer that solved it for me. Revert, recursive revert etc. did not work. Thanks!

Comment: Using the NetBeans plugin to delete a dir and then update the repository did not work for me, cause NetBeans does not really remove the dir including its ".svn" contents. So, it was important to do this via terminal. Worked fine, thanks.

Comment: At last! the "--force the_dir_path" is the missing link. Many Thanks. I think this needs adding to several other questions on stack too.

Comment: On the other hand, the only thing that worked for me was `svn revert --depth infinity $missing_dir` <shrug>

Answer (score 14):

You probably want to use the svn revert command rather than going through the process of deleting items and then updating to revert them.  Use the -R switch to recursively revert files/directories.

svn help info for revert is as follows

```
revert: Restore pristine working copy file (undo most local edits).
usage: revert PATH...

  Note:  this subcommand does not require network access, and resolves
  any conflicted states.  However, it does not restore removed directories.

Valid options:
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  -R [--recursive]         : descend recursively, same as --depth=infinity
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                            'immediates', or 'infinity')
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  --changelist ARG         : operate only on members of changelist ARG
                             [aliases: --cl]

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
  --trust-server-cert      : accept unknown SSL server certificates without
                             prompting (but only with '--non-interactive')
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
  --config-option ARG      : set user configuration option in the format:
                                 FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]
                             For example:
                                 servers:global:http-library=serf
```

Comment: Deleting a folder followed by an svn update is a handy way of cleaning up junk/temp files inside that folder.

Comment: And if the folder gets corrupted it's usually faster to simply delete and restore it than trying to repair it.

Comment: Revert does not recreate deleted folders

Comment: @Damien - true, which made this answer confusing for me

Comment: @PeterAjtai Yes, in the manual quoted in the answer it clearly states "However, it does not restore removed directories"! I don't think this answer is helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question "how to restore a locally deleted folder?" and should not be marked as the correct answer. @Bryan Drewery replied with the correct answer below.

Answer (score 7):

use `svn revert (-R) foldername` to bring it back. you have deleted it using `svn rm` and `svn up` will not recreate it for you, because it is still marked as deleted

Comment: He did not do `svn rm` but just `rm`. I also had this problem and reverting did not fix it. Only `update --force` did.

Comment: @Laurent, thanks (if you still are here), if you had that as an answer I would have voted that.

Answer (score 3):

I use for accidentally deleted folder command

SVN UPDATE

on parent folder

Answer (score 0):

```
svn status|grep ^D|^Ct -c9-|xargs -n1 svn revert
```