# Problems with restoring a folder in SVN

Tags: svn, directory, restore

I just deleted a folder in my SVN that I realized I need to keep. I tried what [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566405/svn-how-to-restore-a-locally-deleted-folder) says I should be able to do, but it doesn't work:

```
~/Documents/svn/myProject > svn revert -R sandbox
Skipped 'sandbox'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you delete it from the local machine or did you do an svn delete? Where the files/folders already committed?

Comment: Clarification: Did you delete it from your local copy or from the SVN server? If not sure, tell us how you deleted it exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I deleted with `svn delete`, and I had done at least one `commit` since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You committed the "svn delete"? Then you have 2 Options:

1. You do a reverse merge of the revision that deleted the directory: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo
2. You update your working copy to the revision before the delete, copy the now existing directory elsewhere outside the working copy, then update to HEAD again. Now you can copy the directory back and re-add it. This way you will loose (disconnect) the history of the directory, though.

Comment: Thanks, Turbo J! After putting this off for a while (the folder wasn't **that** important), I went for your solution (2), which was straightforward and good. 

I should probably learn the merging stuff at some point, though...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you deleted it from your local working copy. In which case you can just do an update e.g.

```
> svn update
```

This should bring it back.

Comment: No, I tried that. It did nothing, unfortunately, just returned the revision number.

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck with Tortoise SVN in the past.  If you right click on your working folder, you can view the repository.  From there, it's simple to fetch it back down and then recommit it.

Comment: Thanks, Amy. I guess using a GUI of some sort might be the way to go, since I don't seem to get anywhere with the command line.